# Compiling for VxWorks

Tags: vxworks

I realize this may be a really dumb question.  Please humor me:

**True or False:** The *only* way to compile a program to run on a VxWorks platform is to purchase a development environment like Tornado or Workbench from WindRiver.

(I'm looking for an free/open-source solution to compile for a VxWorks platform.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outside of an academic license (which would use a VxWorks installation anyway), there is not any way to legally compile your code for a vxWorks platform.

Technically, you CAN obtain the GNU toolchain used to compile code for VxWorks.

The issue you will run into is that you won't have access to the header files necessary for compiling your code or the libraries to link against.

Answer (score 1):

One *can* use a generic GNU cross-compiler to generate ELF files, and load them onto a running VxWorks system using the `ld` command. However, I don't recommend it for anything beyond proof-of-concept or initial experimentation -- the VxWorks libraries *and* Wind River's superb documentation of them are both necessary.

On the development host:

```
powerpc-elf-eabi-gcc -c foo.c
```

Then on the target-resident shell, that has mounted a filesystem from the development host (for example, over NFS):

```
-> ld < foo.o
-> main()
```

(Where the function `main()` comes from `foo.c`)

Answer (score 0):

Since VxWorks is proprietary, they made it so you need their tools (Workbench/Tornado), which they supply, in order to develop for their OS.